# how to add border to jquery button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add border to jquery buttons. My code is:

JSP page has both css and javascript,

```
<style type="text/css">
    .borderClass{
        border-color: #C1E0FF;
        border-width:1px;
        border-style: solid;
}
</style>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function xxx() {
        jQuery("#completedInformation").dialog({
            buttons: {
                Cancel: function() {
                     jquery( this ).addClass('borderClass');
                 jQuery("#completedInformation").dialog( "close" );
            }
            }  
        });
    }
</script>
```

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) so there is no need to define an additional class to the button.

CSS:

```
#completedInformation ~ .ui-dialog-buttonpane button {
    border: #f00 1px solid;
}
```

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/gnSuw/

Answer (score 0):

You can add class to the button's in Dialog -

```
function xxx() 
{
    jQuery("#completedInformation").dialog({
         buttons: [{
               Cancel: function() {                         
                     jQuery("#completedInformation").dialog( "close" );
               },
             'class':'borderClass'
         }]  
    });
}
```

For more info see [jQuery Buttons](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons)

And you can have make sure that your custom styles does not get overridden by jQuery UI styles, by adding `!important` to css rules.

```
.borderClass{
  border-color: #ff0000 !important;
  border-width:1px !important;
  border-style: solid !important;
}
```

or as Sergey Kochetov suggested -

```
#completedInformation .borderClass{
  border: 1px solid #C1E0FF;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/moazzam_khan/Hz3GP/6/)

Comment: -1 http://jsfiddle.net/Hz3GP/5/ Doesn't work. The style is overridden by jQuery UI CSS.

Comment: @iambriansreed.. how to disable jQuery UI CSS for this 'borderClass'?

Comment: @iambriansreed Thanks - fixed. @Hello - you cannot disable a css style unless you remove it from HTML, but you can override it using `!important` or using a more specific selector. Read more about CSS Selectors at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

Comment: @MoazzamKhan Note: `#completedInformation .ui-dialog-buttonpane button` not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 jQuery("#completedInformation").dialog({
         buttons: [{
               Cancel: function() {                         
                     jQuery("#completedInformation").dialog( "close" );
               },
             'class':'borderClass'
         }]  
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hz3GP/)

[**Documentation**](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons)

Comment: -1 http://jsfiddle.net/Hz3GP/5/ Doesn't work. The style is overridden by jQuery UI CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. This is from

You can also:

1. Use Developer Tools in the browser (Chrome has great ones).
2. See what class from jQuery UI defines the button color.
3. Override it in your CSS file with the "!important" attribute.

For example, when I needed to override jQuery UI spinner control and remove the borders, I found the class that defines the borders using Chrome Dev Tools. Then in CSS: I added something like that:

. { border: 0px !important; }

Works great!

Answer (score -1):

This might help:

```
<style>
    .toggler { width: 500px; height: 200px; position: relative; }
    #button { padding: .5em 1em; text-decoration: none; }
    #effect { width: 240px;  padding: 1em;  font-size: 1.2em; border: 1px solid #000; background: #eee; color: #333; }
    .newClass { text-indent: 40px; letter-spacing: .4em; width: 410px; height: 100px; padding: 30px; margin: 10px; font-size: 1.6em; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
      $( "#effect" ).addClass( "newClass", 1000, callback );
      return false;
    });

    function callback() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $( "#effect" ).removeClass( "newClass" );
      }, 1500 );
    }
  });
  </script>
```

Adds classes to elements while animating all style changes.

Source: http://jqueryui.com/addClass/

Comment: `...it might not help either.` This still doesn't answer the OP's question. By the way pseudo-classes much? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes